# When do you need the 的 at the end of sentences? E.g. 你是从哪里听到这个消息的？

Tags: grammar, usage, particles

I learned the following sentence.

> 你是从哪里听到这个消息的？

Is it possible to omit 的 here?  So is 你是从哪里听到这个消息？ wrong?

I know that the particle is used to signal ownership, but is it necessary to use it here?

Information seems to be a noun already?

Comment: grammar topic:  是。。。的 sentence, generally each can be omitted, search site for previous discussion

Comment: verb ... 的 =  what/that/which/where ... verb.   你是从哪里听到这个消息的 = which man you heard the message from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are almost the same meanings:
你从哪里听到这个消息？
你从哪里听到**的**这个消息？
你从哪里听到这个消息**的**？
你**是**从哪里听到**的**这个消息？
你**是**从哪里听到这个消息**的**？